# Horizontal line across a Text component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a horizontal line go across a **Text** component but I didn't figure out how to do it.

I'm trying to recreate this in react native: [image: Horizontal line across a word from CSS]

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
<Text
  style={{
    textDecorationLine: 'line-through',
    textDecorationStyle: 'solid',
  }}
>
  line-through
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through', textDecorationStyle: 'solid'}}> Test <Text />
```